# Android Json with searchview

Tags: java, android, json, xml, gridview

I'm having troubles with adding a searchview to a Json results. I can use the searchview without the Json, but not together.

In this example, If I write something on the searchview, all the gridview disappears. It´s like the searchview doesn´t receive anything.

I made the Json from this tutorial: http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/

And the searchview from this: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview

The results I have in a Gridview

**public class Tab3**

```
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class Tab3 extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {


     SearchView editsearch;


     GridView lv;
     ArrayList < Actors > actorsList = new ArrayList < > ();
     ActorAdapter adapter;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view, container, false);
      GridView gridview = (GridView) vw.findViewById(R.id.gridviewFilms);


      ArrayList < Actors > actorsList = getAllItemObject();
      ActorAdapter customAdapter = new ActorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.jsonparsedata_item, actorsList);
      gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
      gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent filmInfo = new Intent(getContext(), FilmInfo.class);
        filmInfo.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(filmInfo);
       }
      });
      new JSONAsynTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
      //    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.jsonparsedata_item, actorsList);

      // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
      lv = (GridView) vw.findViewById(R.id.gridviewFilms);

      // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
      adapter = new ActorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.jsonparsedata_item, actorsList);

      // Binds the Adapter to the ListView

      lv.setAdapter(adapter);

      editsearch = (SearchView) vw.findViewById(R.id.search);
      editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

      return vw;
     }


     class JSONAsynTask extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Boolean > {
      String result;

      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(String...urls) {

       try {
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

         JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
         JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");


         for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

          Actors actor = new Actors();

          actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
          actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
          actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
          actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
          actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
          actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
          actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
          actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

          actorsList.add(actor);
         }

         return true;
        }

       } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return false;

      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       if (result == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
      }
     }

     private ArrayList < Actors > getAllItemObject() {
      //esto devuelve los valores a los titulos. Esta muy guarro, deberia de estarlo arriba

      return actorsList;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
      String text = newText;
      adapter.filter(text);
      return false;
     }
    }
```

**public class ActorAdapter**

```
public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < Actors > {
// ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;
private List < Actors > animalNamesList = null;
private ArrayList < Actors > arraylist;


public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList < Actors >  objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    //   this.actorList = objects;
    this.animalNamesList = objects;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList < Actors > ();
    this.arraylist.addAll(objects);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvDescription;
    public TextView tvDOB;
    public TextView tvCountry;
    public TextView tvHeight;
    public TextView tvSpouse;
    public TextView tvChildren;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return animalNamesList.size();
}

@Override
public Actors getItem(int position) {
    return animalNamesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.tvCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.director);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.clapboard);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(animalNamesList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.tvName.setText(animalNamesList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvCountry.setText(animalNamesList.get(position).getCountry());
    return v;

}



private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask < String,
Void,
Bitmap > {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( in );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    animalNamesList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        animalNamesList.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (Actors wp: arraylist) {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                animalNamesList.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

}
```

**public class Actors**

```
public class Actors {

private String name;
private String description;
private String dob;
private String country;
private String height;
private String spouse;
private String children;
private String image;

public Actors() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Actors(String name, String description, String dob, String  country,
              String height, String spouse, String children, String image) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.country = country;
    this.height = height;
    this.spouse = spouse;
    this.children = children;
    this.image = image;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
}

public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
    this.spouse = spouse;
}

public String getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(String children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}}
```

**jsonparse_fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Pelikulen izenak..."
    android:background="#f70">

    <requestFocus />
</SearchView>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridviewTab3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp" />
```

**jsonparsedata_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorText"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="15dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/director"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextDark"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextDark"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/director"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/milian"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Finally, I didn´t finish, and I leave it without it.